# Need help in validating suggesting the design for a poker game

Tags: publish-subscribe, p2p, libwebsockets

I'm developing fully decentralized poker game. At the moment my current design is I'm using pub/sub, push/pull sockets using the nano sockets to establish the communication.

Players push the data using nn_push socket type, dealer receives the data using nn_pull socket type, Once the dealer receives the data it processes it and publish the data using nn_pub and all the players in the game receive the data using nn_sub socket type.

Everything working fine so far, the only constraint here I see is my player nodes should know the IP of the dealer and this should be static in order to have this socket communications to work.

And also the players backend is connected from the GUI using libwebsockets for this I need static IP for my backend nodes too.

To summarize, I ended up in a situation where my dealer and playing nodes needs to have the static IP. I'm reading about dht protocols but not sure if those p2p protocols really be applicable in the context of pub/sub model.

Any inputs on how I avoid dependency on using static IP's is greatly helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use LSD and DHT both. LSD is really good for local neighbor nodes, and DHT can do what you want as you describe above. What's more, if you want to use a tracker, that may be much easier than use DHT, since you need to consider more about NAT Traversal if using DHT.